# Mongo Driver current connection

Tags: mongodb

My java code connects to the mongo DB using a single instance of com.mongodb.DB. Now i use this db instance to span 500 threads that executed commands to my db. All of them run in parallel concurrently. The following is the conf params:

```
autoConnectRetry = true; 
connectionsPerHost=50; 
threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier=800; 
connectTimeout=20000; 
socketTimeout=60000; 
maxWaitTime=2000;
```

Now if i check my db using "db.serverStatus().connections" i get the following result : "current" : 52, "available" : 19999, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(3681).... which look ok to me...

I had written the code such that even after all the threads are complete, my main class still runs in a loop so that my JVM is still up. But i see that until i stop my JVM all these 52 connections are still active. Now i execute the same program again, he takes up another 50. How can i make the connections free once the executions to the db is over. IS it very necessary to stop the JVM to release them. Moreover i dont think close() is a good option to call for each thread, as i will have to create a connection from scratch for each thread..

If this was my app server based application, then probably the numbers would never reduce as the JVM will not stop after a db call.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Java driver will only release/close connections when the application exits or the MongoClient is closed.

There is a Jira ticket ([JAVA-424](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-424)) to shrink the connection pool over time.  It has already been fixed in the 3.0 version currently being developed.

Generally, MongoDB has no problems with lots of connections (thousands) so running even a 50 or 100 instances of your application should not become an issue.

I am not sure why you have the main loop keeping the application running but maybe it can detect when the worker threads are finished and close the MongoClient and the re-create it once there is more work to be done?

HTH,
Rob

Comment: Thank Rob.If mongo is not releasing the connections till the app exit , it would mean that in my real time server deployment, the current connection number will keep piling as my appl is not going to stop for a long time. Wont this lead to a situation where i have a very huge number of connections opened, most of which are already complete with their process, but not released because of the application not stopping.Is it ok to close the connection after each db transaction. Whats the overhead of creating a client connection every time

Comment: If you have a server application that is receiving more requests/work over time and it is using a single MongoClient for all of those requests then that application instance will only open the 50 connections and reuse them for the life of the application. If the application is on a cron to handle a batch/terminate and there are several batches running at one time then you can probably reduce the number of connections to MongoDB as I suspect it is not the limiting factor. Can you add more detail to the question on exactly how your application works and interacts with MongoDB?

Comment: I have my app running in a HA server with min of 16 JVMs in total. Each of these JVM will be accessing my DB for for each the maxConnToHost = 100. Now all my JVMs in total will have (16*100)1600 connections to the Db. isnt this heavy? i see an option maxIdleTimeMS with mongo which i think would clean the unused connections, but dont find a way to set it with my java driver. i am using 2.11.2 version

Comment: I get the foll exception at times                                     Sep 19, 2013 12:07:08 AM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError
WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to localhost/127.0.0.1:27017 b/c of error
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)

Comment: 1600 is not a lot. My servers handle more than that in operations. You can always reduce the maximum number of connections per JVM if you do not need them.  The exception is "normal" when there is a transient error.  The maxIdleTimeMS is only supported in 3.0.0 (that I know of).

Comment: So i am safe if the total available connections count in my mongodb is greater than the total number of connections that my drivers would establish(from all JVMs) to the db. I mean in my case where there are 14 client programs with each having 100 maxConnToHost, my available connections at the start of mongod service should be greater than 1400. Please correct me if i am wrong.